# How to lock the result of the output cell, once it meets a criteria, from subsequent value change in the input cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**I'm looking to solve this situation:**

Depending on the value —variable in time— in B1 (input cell), print a specific "status" in the output cell (D1).

**With 3 possible status:**

1st: "VALID"

2nd: "PENDING"

3rd: "APPROVED"

**with the 3 main properties:**

A1 = value fixed (doesn't change in time)

B1 = value changing in time

C1 = string "APPROVED" (to be inputted manually)

D1 = output cell

**Following this formula:**

```
=IFS(len(C1),"APPROVED",B1>A1,"VALID",B1<=A1,"PENDING",TRUE,"ERROR")
```

**What I'm trying to do is:**

As soon as B1>A1 ("VALID" status) changes to B1<=A1 ("PENDING" status), have the D1 cell status "PENDING" locked to "PENDING". 
I.e. not reverting to "VALID" if/when B1<=A1 changes back to B1>A1.

Additionally, only unlocking the "PENDING" status to the "APPROVED" status if the condition for the Status "APPROVED" (len(C1)-manually inputting the string "APPROVED" into C1) is met subsequently.

**Here a simple example of expected result:**

### **At T1** (say, May 27 2019, 12:15pm):

**B1>A1 -> Status= VALID**

A1 = 1.2 (in A1, fixed number)

B1 = 1.5 (in B1, number variable in time)

C1 = (empty cell)

D1 = **VALID**

### **At T2** (say, May 27 2019, 1:15pm):

**B1<=A1 -> Status= PENDING**

A1 = 1.2 (say May 27 2019, 12:15pm)

B1 = **1.2 (or 1.1)** (in B1, number variable in time)

C1 =  (empty cell)

D1 = **PENDING**

### **At T3** (say, May 27 2019, 2:15pm):

**B1>A1 -> Status= PENDING (no revert back to VALID despite B1 reverting to B1>A1)**

A1 = 1.2 (in A1, fixed number)

B1 = **1.4** (in B1, number variable in time)

C1 = (empty cell)

D1 = **PENDING**

### **At T4** (say, May 27 2019, 3:15pm):

A1 = 1.2 (in A1, fixed number)

B1 = **1.4 or 1.1** (in B1, number variable in time)

D1 = **APPROVED** (because of manual input of any character into C1)

C1 = **(any lenght of character into C1)**

**(User manually input any character/string into C1 -> Status= APPROVED (because of len(C1), the PENDING Status gets unlocked to APPROVED status)**

**At T3 is the issue I'm currently facing.**

With this formula:

```
=IFS(len(C1),"APPROVED",B1>A1,"VALID",B1<=A1,"PENDING",TRUE,"ERROR")
```

**The "PENDING" status (gained from T2) reverts back to "VALID"**

**How can one lock the "PENDING" status as soon as B1>A1 ("VALID" status) changes to B1<=A1 ("PENDING" status)?**

**Then unlock the "PENDING" status when the "APPROVED" string is manually typed into D1?**

New question:
Can we color and bold code the status as well?

For example:

Cells A22 to A25 in the sheet below.

Sheet here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UjjMnLmNbEDUfXjeCIOgBZwYqTeXdm_t_4N45OL0k6I/edit#gid=0

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Sorry forgot to make it public. Here it is: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UjjMnLmNbEDUfXjeCIOgBZwYqTeXdm_t_4N45OL0k6I/edit#gid=0

Comment: I also had to correct the formula to put the len argument in front to make the approved work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry forgot to make it public. Here it is: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UjjMnLmNbEDUfXjeCIOgBZwYqTeXdm_t_4N45OL0k6I/edit#gid=0

Comment: for this, you will need a script which will store the previous status and then check against it

Comment: Ok thanks! Do you know where I could find info about doing it? Where can I learn to do it with script?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me the way! I've found the basic formulation in app script to reproduce my IF/IFS formula, + cusomizing the text color and weight using custom function. But still, I don't see where to begin to look to lock/store the "PENDING" status. Do you see a way to do it? Or know some reference documentation? Thanks again.

Comment: Finally found a solution! Thanks again for the guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it sorted!

It was a matter of order of precedence of operations similar to the IFS function mode of operations:

### 1st operation statement:

The 1st If statement regarding the "APPROVED" status as 1st instruction to the machine.

### 2nd operation statement:

(To which the machine continues computing If 1st is `FALSE`)

Proceed to the "PENDING" status IF statement (regular) as 2nd operation instruction to the machine.

### 3rd operation instruction:

(To which the machine continues computing If 1st is (still) `FALSE` and the 2nd statement is (still) `TRUE`)

Proceed to locking the ""PENDING" status in cell D1, if Cell D1 contains the string "PENDING" (inherited from 2nd operation statement found as `TRUE` before) (statusCell = "PENDING" —> D1 = "PENDING")

### 4th operation statement:

(To which the machine continues computing If neither 1st, 2nd/3rd operations statements are `TRUE`)

Proceed to the "VALID" status IF statement as 4th/3rd operation instruction to the machine.

### Machine reasoning mode:

The machine must thus proceed to perform its operations in a backward fashion comparing to usual human thinking: 1st APPROVED, then PENDING, Then Lock PENDING, and finally VALID.

### Edit (Jun 9th 2019):

I corrected some minor errors in the script:

[LOCKVALUECOLORBOLDWORDS for LOCKVALUE&COLOR&BOLDWORDS, (statusCell == "PENDING") for (statusCell = "PENDING"), and the comment [1.] if the value of approveCell is not-blank..., for [1.] if the value of approveCell is blank...)].
(I must have forgotten somehow to save it before posting it).

Now it's working as expected.

Here the Sheet:

[How to lock the result of the output cell, once it meets a criteria, from subsequent value change in the input cell in Google Sheets?](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UjjMnLmNbEDUfXjeCIOgBZwYqTeXdm_t_4N45OL0k6I/edit#gid=0)

But for some reason, the function needs to execute twice after each edit to print the new status.

Video demo here:

https://youtu.be/DEI7RGRotcs

I'll see why it is so and look for how to figure out how to make it print after single execution.

New Script so far:

https://pastebin.com/gxK0bvcu

```
/**
* Locks the Status of a cell according to criteria and Colors and bolds the specific words of status
*
* @param arg3:  Colors "VALID" Status to orange, "PENDING" Status to green, and "APPROVED" to purple
*
* @customfunction
*/


function LOCKVALUECOLORBOLDWORDS(arg3) {

      var app = SpreadsheetApp;
      var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

      //(read left to right) get the value from range A1:A1, from active sheet, and assign it the variable "fixedvalueCell"
      var fixedvalueCell = activeSheet.getRange(1, 1).getValue();

      //(read left to right) get the value from range B1:B1, from active sheet, and assign it the variable "changingvalueCell"
      var changingvalueCell = activeSheet.getRange(1, 2).getValue();

      //(read left to right) get the value from range C1:C1, from active sheet, and assign it the variable "approveCell"
      var approveCell = activeSheet.getRange(1, 3).getValue();

      //(read left to right) get the value from range D1:D1, from active sheet, and assign it the variable "statusCell"
      var statusCell = activeSheet.getRange(1, 4).getValue(); 




      //[1.] if the value of approveCell is not-blank, then set/print "APPROVED" into D1, and color it to purple, and bold it.
      if 
        (approveCell !== "") {
        activeSheet.getRange(1, 4).setValue("APPROVED").setFontColor("#7F00FF").setFontWeight("bold");
      } 


      //[2.] if the value of changingvalueCell is smaller or equal to the value of fixedvalueCell, then set/print "PENDING" into D1, and color it to green, and bold it.
        else if 
        (changingvalueCell <= fixedvalueCell) {
        activeSheet.getRange(1, 4).setValue("PENDING").setFontColor("#7FFF00").setFontWeight("bold");
      } 


      //[3.] if the value of statusCell is "PENDING", then set/print "PENDING" into D1, and color it to green, and bold it.
        else if 
        (statusCell == "PENDING") {
        activeSheet.getRange(1, 4).setValue("PENDING").setFontColor("#7FFF00").setFontWeight("bold");
      }


      //[4.] if all [1.] and [2.] and [3.] IF statements are FALSE (for everything else), then set/print "VALID" into D1, and color it to orange, and bold it.
        else {
        activeSheet.getRange(1, 4).setValue("VALID").setFontColor("#FF6600").setFontWeight("bold");
      }


      var result = arg3;

      return result;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the 2nd argument to enable change of status from "PENDING" to "APPROVED" upon typing into C1 any character lenght, I've added the IFS function len(C1) app script equivalent:

```
/**
* Stores Status 'PENDING' As soon as B1>A1 changes to B1<=A1
*
* @param arg1: The "PENDING" status that will be stored as soon as B1>A1 changes to B1<=A1
* Unlocks 'PENDING' status to 'APPROVED" status when manual typing in C1
*
* @customfunction
*/

//The 'approveCell !== ""' status changes the 'PENDING' status to 
//"APPROVED' in D1 when manually typing in C1



function STATUSPENDING(arg1) {

  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  var fixedvalueCell = activeSheet.getRange(1, 1).getValue();
  var changingvalueCell = activeSheet.getRange(1, 2).getValue();
  var approveCell = activeSheet.getRange(1, 3).getValue(); 
  var statusCell = activeSheet.getRange(1, 4).getValue(); 


  if 
    (approveCell !== "") {
    activeSheet.getRange(1, 4).setValue("APPROVED");
  } 
    else if 
    (changingvalueCell <= fixedvalueCell) {
    activeSheet.getRange(1, 4).setValue("PENDING");
  } 
    else {
    activeSheet.getRange(1, 4).setValue("VALID");
  }


  var result = arg1;

  return result;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add colors and boldness to text Status, I've added the .setFontColor and .setFontWeight arguments to app script code:

```
/**
* Colors specific words 
*
* @param arg2:  Colors "VALID" Status to orange, "PENDING" Status to gree, and "APPROVED" to purple
*
* @customfunction
*/


function COLORWORDS(arg2) {

  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  var fixedvalueCell = activeSheet.getRange(1, 1).getValue();
  var changingvalueCell = activeSheet.getRange(1, 2).getValue();
  var approveCell = activeSheet.getRange(1, 3).getValue(); 
  var statusCell = activeSheet.getRange(1, 4).getValue(); 


  if 
    (approveCell !== "") {
    activeSheet.getRange(1, 4).setValue("APPROVED").setFontColor("#7F00FF").setFontWeight("bold");
  } 
    else if 
    (changingvalueCell <= fixedvalueCell) {
    activeSheet.getRange(1, 4).setValue("PENDING").setFontColor("#7FFF00").setFontWeight("bold");
  } 
    else {
    activeSheet.getRange(1, 4).setValue("VALID").setFontColor("#FF3D0D").setFontWeight("bold");
  }


  var result = arg2;

  return result;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

So far here's where I've come.

After some research I've laned how to use the basic app script custom function, succeding in reproducing the if statement as below. 
but I still don't see how to store the "PENDING" status once it has been verified by the  B1<=A1 argument. As is, the script below reverts back to "VALID" status when B1 value turns back to B1>A1.

How to formulate this missing storing argument in app script?

```
/**
* Stores Status 'PENDING' As soon as B1>A1 changes to B1<=A1
*
* @param arg1: The "PENDING" status that will be stored as soon as B1>A1 changes to B1<=A1
* @customfunction
*/


function STATUSPENDING(arg1) {

  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  var fixedvalueCell = activeSheet.getRange(1, 1).getValue();
  var changingvalueCell = activeSheet.getRange(1, 2).getValue();
  var statusCell = activeSheet.getRange(1, 4).getValue(); 

  if(changingvalueCell <= fixedvalueCell) {
    activeSheet.getRange(1, 4).setValue("PENDING");
  } else {
    activeSheet.getRange(1, 4).setValue("VALID");
  }


  var result = arg1;

  return result;

}
```